# Is this clip repairable?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, pci-express

On my Gigabyte X670E Aorus Master I noticed that the clamp of the PCIex 5.0 16x connector seems damaged:

[image]

[image]

Is it repairable?
I'm afraid it can lead to wrong contact of the graphic board.

Comment: The clip is not actually a requirement for the gpu. It should work without as long as it is otherwise secured properly.

Comment: @LPChip good to know, thanks. I was afraid since I have some issues with the GPU and I was wondering about this clip. Hence I'll investigate elsewhere.